# Winforms | Ссылка не указывает на экземляр объекта

Tags: c#, winforms, null

Ошибка при обращении к словарю в Form из Usercontrol.

*Form1.cs*

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public Dictionary<string, int> TeamDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

*TestsPage.cs*

```
public partial class TestsPage : UserControl
    {

        public TestsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private Form1 mainform = ((Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"]);

        ......

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mainform.TeamDict.Count);
        }
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Test3.exe

> Additional information: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Словарь не пуст.

Comment: Лучше заведите в своём Контроле поле для словаря и когда размещаете  Контрол - записывайте руками в него словарь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private Form1 mainform = ((Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"]);
```

Эта строка кода выполняется при конструировании юзерконтрола. В этот момент форма ещё не открыта. Соответственно, `mainForm` равно `null`.

Перенесите код получения формы непосредственно в том место, где она нужна: в событие `button2_Click`.

Comment: `mainForm равно null` а как же `InvalidCastException`?

Comment: @aepot - не пойму, о чём речь?

Comment: Всё, покурил доки, всё ок, это я тупанул. Плюсик стоит.